# Has Selenium IDE Stopped Working for firefox?

Tags: selenium, firefox

Is it true that selenium IDE no longer works for firefox?
Whats the future of web automation, please guide, thanks

http://get.usetrace.com/selenium-ide/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI1Kjb7K6W1wIVQSNoCh0GsARREAAYASAAEgL4z_D_BwE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the official firefox website , yes, selenium IDE will not work on firefox 55 and above . You can read about it, [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/)

As for your second question,though its pretty wide, below are some articles I found out that I think can help you out

https://www.qasymphony.com/blog/future-software-testing-3-predictions/
https://www.techwell.com/techwell-insights/2017/04/think-differently-about-future-software-testing
https://www.quora.com/What-will-be-future-trends-in-software-testing-2017-feild-Specially-in-automation-testing

This one talks about future of DOM based testing tool
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9608/future-of-dom-based-ui-testing

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Selenium IDE [has stopped working on Firefox 55](https://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2017/08/09/firefox-55-and-selenium-ide/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20Selenium%20%28The%20Official%20Selenium%20Blog%29) onwards.
Alternative solutions for now could be:

- Protractor
- Robot Framework
- Katalon Studio

**Updated**: Katalon Studio has just launched a promising plugin for Chrome called "[Katalon Automation Recorder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/katalon-automation-record/ljdobmomdgdljniojadhoplhkpialdid)". It is introduced to support users who no longer be able to record and playback automation tests using the obsolete Selenium IDE or users of popular open source frameworks looking for a handy recorder